# Is gvfs-trash installed? in Atom

Tags: vagrant, atom-editor, gvfs

When I tried to remove a file in local machine to check files are synchronous with vagrant development server it pops up an error:

```
The following file couldn't be moved to the trash.
Is gvfs-trash installed?
```

For solving it I created a trash directory that can be accessed from outside the user’s home directory:

```
# Create a Trash directory (with some subdirectories) in root
sudo mkdir -p /.Trash-1000/{expunged,files,info}

# Give ownership of this to your user:
sudo chown -R $USER /.Trash-1000
```

Still I can't remove the file from local machine. But If I delete a file at vagrant development server it automatically deletes at local machine, opposite is not happening and ends-up with this error "Is gvfs-trash installed? "

Comment: Did you have a look at the issue reported [here](https://github.com/atom/tree-view/issues/799)?

Comment: cd /media/yourPartition
sudo mkdir .Trash-1000
sudo chown -R yourUser:yourUser .Trash-1000/

Comment: @idleberg above code from the link provided worked for me.  Answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/atom/tree-view/issues/799) on GitHub reporting this problem. According to the report, a missing `.Trash-1000` can cause this problem, so you can create it as follows.

```
mnt=/; id=$(id -u); sudo mkdir -p "$mnt/.Trash-$id"/{expunged,files,info} \
  && sudo chown -R $USER:$USER "$mnt/.Trash-$id"/ \
  && sudo chmod -R o-rwx "$mnt/.Trash-$id"/
```

Set `mnt` to the mount point, where gvfs-trash is expecting it.
Simply cd to the directory which will be opened in atom and execute `df .`.
This will give something like this:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      960380628 463122460 448403708  51% /mnt/vol
```

In this example, the mount point and the value of `mnt` would be `/mnt/vol`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, but I had to modify it a bit:  `sudo mkdir -p /.Trash-1000/{expunged,files,info} && sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /.Trash-1000/`

Comment: This did not work with me on Ubuntu 16.04 and Atom 1.4x versions.

Answer (score 2):

Like **YuriAFGomes** said, everything seemed to work fine in my system: trash folder had the right permissions and *gvfs-trash* worked flawlessly from command line, yet *atom* 1.45 said it couldn't delete any file. Tried to start atom with *sudo* and it didn't fix anything. Tried creating the *.Trash-1000* directories in several places, and nothing, same error related to *gvfs-trash*. I'm pretty sure this used to work fine in my *atom* setup and suddenly it stopped doing so, and I have no idea why. I went to their [releases list](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases) and tried downgrading to several of them until I settled with version 1.30, which doesn't seem to have this issue and is compatibles with my local packages. If you have this problem and tried everything said around the web, I suggest you try downgrading to different versions until the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

What solved this issue for me was uninstalling atom via dpkg and installing it via apt from the following PPA: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/atom . I have no clue why this works, though. I have noticed that the PPA installs atom 1.26, while the version where the issue arised, installed via dpkg, is 1.45.

Before doing that, I have tried creating the .Trash-1000 directories in root, in home and in project folder, with the proper permissions. gvfs-trash was installed, updated and working as expected all the time, but the problem persisted. Really odd.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that atom/electron are/were using gvfs-trash which has been [deprecated](https://github.com/GNOME/gvfs/commit/2f28fa49cfeb1c82927a1c7c0021b15e2742149f) for almost 5 years.  Electron which is the platform on which Atom is built has [fixed this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15011) in the development branch but [hasn't backported it](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15011#issuecomment-433745093) to the 2.0 branch on which Atom is based.

Solution/Workaround as of now?

1. [Use an environment variable](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Atom_(text_editor)#Unable_to_delete_files) `$ELECTRON_TRASH` and set it to `gio` or one of the alternatives
2. See if you are [missing the .Trash-1000 folder](https://github.com/atom/tree-view/issues/799#issuecomment-277127668) (assuming your uid is 1000)
3. Install an [alternate gvfs-trash script](https://github.com/atom/tree-view/issues/1237#issuecomment-434502711) to take over the missing functionality
4. Delete the file/folder outside of atom

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on **Windows** using **Atom**, where I couldnt delete the files. So I resorted to deleting them manually from the directory (outside of Atom).

Turns out atom cannot "move to trash" if u checked in recycle bin this option:
"Don't move files to the Recycle Bin. Remove files immediately when deleted."

Just set the other option (to move files to actual recycle bin) and should work.

Comment: yes, I have same error. There is no solution yet?